# How to test async methods in React?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, enzyme

Could anyone help me with testing of async / Promise based methods in React components? For example I have following really simple React component (it's only dummy code)

```
import server from './server';

class Button extends Component {
  async handleClick() {
    if (await canDoSomething()) {
      const result = await calculateIt();
      if (result) {
        // will be mocked in my unit test
        await server.sendResultToServer(result);
        localStorage.setItem('sent', 'true');
      }
      localStorage.setItem('sent', 'false');
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('sent') === 'true') {
      // do something
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

Now in my test I could mock most of the async methods with sinon like so:

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const promise = Promise.resolve();
  sinon.stub(server, 'sendResultToServer', () => promise);
  const wrapper = shallow(<Button />);
  wrapper.find(<button />).simulate('click');
  // this await will be resolved FIRST. Only then
  // await server.sendResultToServer(result); in my code will be resolved
  await promise;
  expect(localStorage.getItem('sent')).to.equal('true');
})
```

If you first see this code you should think that everything is ok. But unfortunately it's not. In my test I am awaiting the promise `await promise;` and **after** that I make my expectations. But the implementation code also awaits the promise. So when the promise fulfills in **both** places the expectation runs **before** the code in the implementation runs. In other words: my test runs before the code to test (tested on my machine using Mocha / Chai / Enzyme). What I need is the reversed order.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: You never call the click handler in your test

Comment: And how do you test the function handleClick()? In my example it is inside the react component. But I could wrote it above the React component and not export it. So the only one who can access the function is the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger click handler:

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const promise = Promise.resolve();
  sinon.stub(server, 'sendResultToServer', () => promise);
  const wrapper = shallow(<Select />);
  wrapper.simulate('click')
  await promise;
  expect(localStorage.getItem('sent')).to.equal('true');
})
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. That happens when I do a copy and paste. I already did that and thats exactly my problem: *after* the event the promise order is not guaranteed. The promise in the test resolves earlier than the promise in my code. I will update / fix my question.

Comment: What about `canDoSomething` where does it come from, seems like this needs to be mocked as wel

Comment: That's a good question. There is no "exit" in my code at this point. So imagine that I redirect to a new route at this point. Or I do nothing here. I only show an error if one occurs. If no error occurs (sent = true) I do nothing.
Maybe I have some architectural problem here the more I think about it.